# Laravel 5.4 - form/API/view

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, view

I created an API (*store*) that saves the data on the database and returns 201 if successful or 404 if not.

```
if ($visit->save()){
    $visit->view_visit = [
    'href' => 'api/v1/visit/' . $visit->id,
    'method' => 'GET'
     ];
     $response = [
         'msg' => 'Visit created.',
         'visit' => $visit
     ];
     return response()->json($response, 201);
}
$response = [
    'msg' => 'Error during creation.'
    ];
return response()->json($response, 404);
```

It works perfectly. Using postman you can see that the status will be <<201 Created>>.

This API should be used in two ways: called by another application or called by a Laravel form. This is the question:

How do I call it in a way if it successful, it will load a given view on the browsers? 
In other words, is there a way to make the form call a route (the api itself, something like ../api/visit/) and in case of success loads the other view? Also, I would like to pass the content of response['msg'] to this new view.

I know I could do it inside the *store* method by filtering the HTTP referrer, but I would like to keep the controller code strictly to manage the record creation. Besides that, I have to send the 201/404 codes along with the returned data.

I also considered creating another controller to handle the API response and then call the form, but it still sounds too much -- it's supposed to be easy, I guess.

Comment: BTW, the correct code shows
`method' => 'POST`
instead of 
`method => 'GET`

Comment: check the answer out

Comment: Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Comment: @Ross, thanks! I did what Sletheren recommended and it worked very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In laravel you can use a helpful method which determines if the request that has been sent is an AJAX request or just a normal request, which is:

```
$request->wantsJson()
```

So, Inside your controller in the return function, you will make an if statement:

```
if ($request->wantsJson()) {
  return response()->json();
}else{
  return view(...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Sletheren! Worked perfectly -  (I knew it should have an elegant solution!). 
I just added the below header to the JSON response and the Laravel did its magic
`$visit->headers = [
    'Accept'        => 'application/json',
    'CONTENT_TYPE'  => 'application/json'
];`